# How to map object data or two arrays at the same time inside JSX

Tags: arrays, json, object, jsx

I guess my problem is simple but i can't solve it. Could you help? I should make a simple graph bar data visualization based on JSON array data (a part of the JSON array is below):

```
{
      name: "R",
      year: 1956,
    },
    {
      name: "K",
      year: 1956,
    },
    {
      name: "P",
      year: 1982,
    },
    {
      name: "E",
      year: 1982,
    },
    {
      name: "S",
      year: 1992,
    }
```

The idea is to map `<tr><div>{year}</div><div className="graph-bar" style={{ width: '${amount}px' * 10 }}></div><div>{amount}</div></tr>` to each row to tell how many names were given in each year. So I reduced the JSON array to an object and calculated the amounts of the duplicate years:

`Object { 1956: 7, 1982: 11, 1983: 2, 1989: 1, 1990: 2, 1991: 2, 1993: 2, 1994: 1, 1996: 1, 1998: 1, … }`.

I have two questions:

1. Can I map an object like above in JSX to the form given above?
2. How can I use a multiplier (10 in this case) in inline CSS? This is not working: `style={{ width: '${amount}px' * 10 }}`. *I have replaced backticks inside the inline style because I could not get them work here. Without the multiplier the backtick width is working*. I have tried also calc() but it is not working.

As a plan B I have also made two simple arrays:

`years = [ 1956, 1982, 1983, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 1996, 1998, … ]`

`amount = [ 7, 11, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, … ]`

If it is impossible map an object how can I map two arrays at the same time or is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you provided code wise it is hard to really determine exactly what you are going for but to map key value pairs you can use this:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
}
```

then use your key value as you would like.

For number 2:

`` style={{width: `${amount * 10}px`}} ``